# How to change the background color of a DataGrid row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, onmouseover

I have a DataGrid and I want to change the background color of the whole row when I mouse over.

I tried using `e.Item.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.color='red'";` but this only changes the color of the text in the row. I want to highlight the full row.
How do I set the background color to change the row in the DataGrid in the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub DataGridID_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles DataGridID.ItemDataBound

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

        ' Do the mouseover and mouseout javascript
        Dim oBGcolour As String

        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
            oBGcolour = Right(Hex(DataGridID.ItemStyle.BackColor.ToArgb()), 6)
        ElseIf e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            oBGcolour = Right(Hex(DataGridID.AlternatingItemStyle.BackColor.ToArgb()), 6)
        End If

        e.Item.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.background='#cdcdcd';")
        e.Item.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.background='#" & oBGcolour & "';")

    End If

End Sub
```